# Google Maps v2 android crash when internet connection not available

Tags: android, google-maps

that showing google map API v2 with android. sometimes my app crash when no internet connection, like when i put GOOGLE Place API. when i clicked ATM and no internet then app will crash.
 i want to make a exception , so when no internet connection, then the map can show a notification that phone doest have a internet connection.

found soulution for this problem
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-detect-internet-connection-status/

Comment: why don't you put some code that checks for internet activity once the app starts? [chech this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/android-detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available)

Comment: alr used that code, but sometimes the internet not available, so apps will crash

Comment: did you check it with a device? what sort of internet connection are you using? on a device, if you are using a wifi connection, codes that were put earlier as answers will work, but if you are using data connection(mobile operator internet) then these codes might not work. Secondly, I have a feeling, but not sure, the codes available here does not work when you check for internet conectivity on an emulator. Please specify what type of connection you are checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to Put this code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (servicesOK()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.testmap);

    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activitymain);

    }


}

public boolean servicesOK() {

    int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

        return true;

    } else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {

        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable,
                this, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
        dialog.show();

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Can not connect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    return false;
}
```

This might help you..:)

Comment: Hi Mike i still cannot resolved that problem, would you mind to check the code here http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-using-google-places-api-and-google-map-android-api-v2/

and how when no internet connections and users click FIND button.

Comment: Hi mike this is mainactivity code and JSON parser http://pastebin.com/hkQSwEHE

this JSON Parser http://pastebin.com/v7MabBdc

Comment: Hey..Thanks for the info.. Did you check with the Manifest ? are all the permissions in place ? Most importantly, the internet permission ?

Comment: Hi mike its not about manifest. its about how to make a exception or Try catch, so when no internet connection the apps will not crash

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to check if there is an internet connection on the device:

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
            .getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null;
}
```

Comment: not like this. i have JSON parsing which is parse Google Places Nearby. so when i click nearby place without internet connection the map will crash

Answer (score 0):

use an if statement to handle the crash.

```
    public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
                .getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null;
    }

if (isNetworkAvailable == true){
//your map code
} else {
Log.e("Error","No network");
 Toast.makeText(this, "no internet" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
}
```

don't forget to have checking the [network permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE) in your manifest.

*the method is taken from *Emmanuel*'s answer

Comment: i mean when parsing from JSON when no internet, everytime no internet my map will crash.